# Shipping reliable OpenCL applications - Tools/Techniques/Tips?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I want to ship OpenCL code that should work on all OpenCL 1.1 compatible GPUs. Rather than buying a bunch of GPUs and testing on them, are there any tools that can help ensure reliability?

If anyone has experience shipping OpenCL applications to a wide hardware base, I'd be interested in knowing about any other methods for testing reliability.

Comment: Video card driver versions can also come into play.  I had some OpenCL code that crashed the compiler (when building kernels) when running on Nvidia hardware until a new release fixed it.

Comment: Yes I have run into similar issues. Also the WDDM timeouts when threads get stuck on the GPU on older h/w and the OS terminates them all.

Answer (score 0):

I've a bit of knowledge on this.  Unfortunately, the answer is: depends on what the kernel is doing.

My biggest gripe is with NVIDIA and OpenCL, since they don't seem to support: vectors (float2, 4, etc) and global offsets.  Kind of obnoxious.  Intel and ATI are both solid, but even then vector sizes can differ.  The above doesn't really matter if you are doing image convolution.

It matters if you want to run AMD FFT on an NVIDIA card, are doing matrix math, etc.  To address the vector issue, you can write multiple kernels that each have a different vector size and call the right one:  MatrixMult_float4(...).

Comment: NVIDIA supports the vector types just fine, they just don't have a vector hardware architecture (neither does AMD anymore either). Granted, you might want to write different kernels for specific hardware architectures, but the vector types are supported in any OpenCL compliant implementation and your statement seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the clarification.  But still, certain hardware is optimized for certain vector lengths, which is found by querying Preferred Vector Width.

Comment: You can query the preferred vector width of each type, then use it in an appropriately(programmatically) changed cl kernel.

Comment: I am using only scalar types, and the kernel for the most part is plain-C code (not using any extensions either) that will process data in parallel. Also - no local or global fences.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your code compiles by using the AMD KernelAnalyzer2, although this does need some component of the Catalyst drivers so it only works for me on PCs with AMD GPUs.  There is also the Intel Kernel Builder, which works for devices with Intel OpenCL SDK support.  Nvidia's implementation has bugs in it, especially on newer GPUs in my experience so there the best is to test one GPU from each generation.

Comment: Is there anything analogous to KernelAnalyzer for Nvidia h/w?

Comment: No there isn't.  Nvidia does not produce development tools for OpenCL anymore.  However, you can achieve an almost identical result by using the build option -cl-std=CL1.1 (recent Nvidia GPUs) or -cl-std=CL1.0 for older Nvidia GPUs in AMD KernelAnalyzer2.  This changes the version of OpenCL C used in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid extensions and validate CL language versions, one could try to test compile the code using the LLVM, or just getting the grammar for validation, e.g. as BNF.

There's a promising open source project, which probably contains useful stuff: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pocl/pocl/master/files/head:/lib/CL/

However, the problems I encountered were:

- Newline characters caused build breakers on certain implementations (CR, LF, CRLF) in OpenCL source files. Specifying one of these as the only valid line ending would be just stupid. If one is editing source files on different platforms in conjunction with an SCM, it could get inconvenient. So I remove comments and clean up line breaks before compilation.
- Performance: Feeding the GPU efficiently using multithreading; different hardware constellations have different bottlenecks. Here I needed a client side pipeline with multiple dispatcher threads. Of course, the amount of work that remains for the CPU depends on the task or capabilities, amount and resources of computing devices. Things that needed serialized execution or dynamic loop counts have been such candidates.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. BTW do you happen to know if there has been any progress on producing IL bytecode to speed up the build?

Comment: You're welcome. Not that I know of, there's neither an IL nor a CIL. The Khronos group would need to specify such a CIL (perhaps they could adopt a subset of LLVM bytecode). For performance alone, you could do a compilation pass with source code and `clGetProgramInfo()` to retrieve the generated binaries for each involved, specific compute device. These blobs can be stored in files and reused with `clCreateProgramWithBinary()`. All this is very similar to OpenGL binary shader formats.